# How Can I Get a single JSON object in an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API using a stored procedure in SQL Server with Entity Framework Core 5.0?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, asp.net5, ef-core-5.0

I’m trying to create a service that responds with a JSON of a single instance of an object.The idea is that from a user ID (`id_user`) it returns a single record from the user table like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "urlImage": " https://i.pinimg.com/474x/d0/e4/e4/d0e4e45662096e2aacdb0b72da38ed85.jpg",
    "name1": " Jefferson",
    "lastName1": "Pardo",
    "city": " Bogotá",
    "country": "string",
    "nickname": " Jeffer",
    "demonym_fem": "colombian",
}
```

When I try to run this endpoint

```
[Route("GetBasicProfile/")]
[ApiController]
public class BasicProfileController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly dbjeffContext _context;

    public BasicProfileController(dbjeffContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/BasicProfile
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<BasicProfile>>> GetBasicProfile(int id)
    {
        SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter(@"id_user", id);

        string StoredProc = "EXEC GetBasicProfile @id_user";

        var BasicProfileReturn = await _context.BasicProfile.FromSqlRaw(StoredProc, param1).ToListAsync();

        return BasicProfileReturn;
    }
}
```

I get this error

> 500
> Undocumented
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'LastName1' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.

I think my problem is in the `FromSqlRaw` function, but I have already tried this way too

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<BasicProfile[]> GetBasicProfile(int id)
{
    BasicProfile[] BasicsProfiles;

    SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter(@"id_user", id);

    BasicsProfiles =  _context.BasicProfile.FromSqlRaw("exec GetBasicProfile @id_user", param1).ToArray();

    return BasicsProfiles;
}
```

Help!! I'm desperate T__T

The stored procedure in SQL Server looks like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBasicProfile]
    (@id_user int)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT 
        id,
        url_image url_image,
        u.name1 name1,
        u.last_name1 last_name1,
        u.city city,
        (SELECT DISTINCT gen_femenino 
         FROM country 
         WHERE id = u.id_country) demonym_fem
    FROM 
        userr u
    WHERE 
        id = @id_user;
END
```

In .NET 5, I have this class

```
public class BasicProfile
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string? UrlImage { get; set; }
    public string? Name1 { get; set; }
    public string? LastName1 { get; set; }
    public string? City { get; set; }
    
    public string? demonym_fem { get; set; }
}
```

And this context class

```
public partial class dbjeffContext: DbContext
{
    public dbjeffContext() { }

    public dbjeffContext(DbContextOptions<dbjeffContext> options)
```

:base(options)
{
}

```
    public virtual DbSet<BasicProfile> BasicProfile { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well, apparently some class property names do not match query result column names (`UrlImage` <-> `url_image`, `LastName1` <-> `last_name1`). Change either of them to match the other, or use data annotations/fluent API to specify column names for properties.

Comment: It worked! I changed the aliases of the columns in the query and it worked, thank you very much